# All possible uses for the Application.SysCmd Method

Tags: ms-access, methods, vba

Is there a place to find all possible uses of the syscmd method in MS Access? I know Microsoft has a [developer reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214117.aspx), but I have found there are many other uses for this method that are not listed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a comprehensive list, including which Access versions each command applies to, translated into English.

http://www.excite-webtl.jp/world/english/web/?wb_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.f3.dion.ne.jp%2F%7Eelement%2Fmsaccess%2FAcTipsUnDocumentedSysCmd.html&wb_lp=JAEN&wb_dis=2

Answer (score 2):

Access itself provides an interface to the full object model of all libraries in use. In the VBE, hit F2 on the keyboard (or, from the VIEW menu, choose OBJECT BROWSER). Type "syscmd" in the search box and you'll get the full details on it. The variable names are verbose enough to explain just about everything you need to know.

EDIT: The object browser doesn't give you anything but the SysCmd functions that have been documented by assigning named constants. But the recommendation to familiarize yourself with the object browser is a good one, especially if you right click on the CLASSES list and choose SHOW HIDDEN MEMBERS -- you can learn a lot from that.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few of the "undocumented" functions, I know from experience that you can basically run anything that windows can do using syscmd once you understand how to structure the commands from examples like these.

http://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Undocumented-SysCmd-Functions

From google search: syscmd access